# GSYNC VSYNC fps unstable problem

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have a screen with GSYNC activated. In NVIDIA's panel, both GSYNC and VSYNC are activated.

I am playing on Counter Strike global offensive with very low graphic parameters.
The computer has a gtx760 and a i7 4770.

In game VSYNC is not activated, my fps is very unstable, sometimes close to 144, sometimes close to 60 fps.
It seems something else is trying to cap it to 60 fps.
My graphic drivers are up-to-date.

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Comment: did you try forcing your refresh rate using the start option "-refresh 144"?

Comment: @RandomDisplayName Yes I tried this option, I also tried -full to force fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the most recent nvidia drivers are not handling GSYNC properly, a hotfix is availble.
http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3738/~/geforce-hotfix-driver-355.80

I hope it helps.